# Manipulating Bars

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Right, so this is what my data looks like:

```
{
    "chartData":[
        {
            "vId":"307",
            "vNm":"Alejandro Rivera Ulloa",
            "values":[
                {"period":"2015-01","amount":37,"id":132},
                {"period":"2015-02","amount":38,"id":133},
                {"period":"2015-03","amount":33,"id":134}
            ]
        },
        {
            "vId":"308",
            "vNm": "Daniel Torres",
            "values": [
                {"period":"2015-01","amount":41,"id":135},
                {"period":"2015-02","amount":41,"id":136},
                {"period":"2015-03","amount":41,"id":137}
            ]
        },
        {
            "vId":"309",
            "vNm": "Pablo Alvarez Garcia",
            "values":[
                {"period":"2015-01","amount":16,"id":138},
                {"period":"2015-02","amount":17,"id":139},
                {"period":"2015-03","amount":14,"id":140}
            ],
        },
        {
            "vId":"391",
            "vNm":"Janette Avalos de Conte",
            "values":[
                {"period":"2015-01","amount":28.5,"id":141},
                {"period":"2015-02","amount":29,"id":142},
                {"period":"2015-03","amount":27.5,"id":143}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I want to have this graph (made with different data) have the bars be the total of each "values" in the data.
 [image]

The reason I didn't compile the value inside the data itself is because this same data will be later used for another graph based on this one.

So, essentially. My question is: How do I make the bars the height of the sums of each individual set of "values"?

If anyone needs clarification, drop a comment.

I've tried to do a d3.sum, but that gives me the general sum, and iterating through an array of sums and pushing each sum into an array isn't a walk in the park with D3.

Comment: Please clarify what you've tried so far, read [ask], create MCVE.

Comment: Do you mean the values represented by the total of each"amount" in your JSON object? Also, please include your actual code that generates the graph, not just the data.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have to work a little bit with your current data: group values by date and reduce by amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function aggregates the data the way you commented:

```
var cookData = function(data){
    var keys = {};
    var result = [];
    var values = data.map(function(d) { return d.values; });
    values.forEach(function (value){
        value.forEach(function (v) {
            if (keys[v.period]) {
                keys[v.period] += v.amount;    
            } else {
                keys[v.period] = v.amount;    
            }
        });
    })
    Object.keys(keys).forEach(function (key) {
        result.push({date: key, amount: keys[key]});
    });
    return result;
};
```

You could easily use this function further on with your bar chart (see [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) for an example on how to create the bar chart).

Comment: Question. Could you take a look and tell me why my bars are not displaying?

Comment: @AlexeyAyzin feel free to create a fiddle and ask a new question, if necessary :)